# The empty path didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

*Using the URLconf defined in personal_portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
projects/
The empty path didn't match any of these.*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("projects/", include("projects.urls")),
]
```

Comment: There is no path here that matches `/` itself, so that is indeed expected behaviour.

Comment: I am new to django and trying to understand how it works thank you very much man .. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like below.

```
path('',include('my_app.urls'))
```

hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: But WHY does this work? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398899/the-empty-path-didnt-match-any-of-these-django