# The empty path didn't match any of these (django)

Tags: django

A similar question was asked here in [The empty path didn't match any of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268663/the-empty-path-didnt-match-any-of-these). The solution did indeed work when I included the `path('',include('projects.urls'))` within `personal_portfolio.py`. But here's what bugs ME...

personal_portfolio/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('projects/', include('projects.urls')),
]
```

projects/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.project_index, name="project_index"),
path("<int:pk>", views.project_detail, name="project_detail"),
]
```

The empty path IS contained (in the latter)! when the `path('projects/', include('projects.urls'))` is called, it should call `projects/urls.py`.

**Then** **the empty path is there**. Why do I need to include `path("",include('projects.urls'))` in `personal_portfolio/urls.py` for it to work?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path("", ...)` is included by `path('projects/', include('projects.urls'))`, therefore the path is:

```
'projects/' + "" = "projects/"
```

Therefore you need to access `localhost:8000/projects/` and a request to `localhost:8000/` will fail.

If you use `path("", include('projects.urls'))` instead, then the path is:

```
 "" + "" = ""
```

Now a request to the empty path `localhost:8000/` will succeed.

Comment: And that's because the first function called is path('projects', ...)

Answer (score 0):

You are using localhost:8000 instead of localhost:8000/projects to access your project.

If you do not have the empty path within your URL, the request will fail.